# Como adicionar valores num dicionário usando input?

Tags: python, dicionário

Criei um dicionário em Python, onde o sistema de cadastramento de livro interage com usuário

O problema que quando adiciono o gênero, eu coloco o mesmo gênero após o loop para verificar se foi adicionado, se caso tivesse sido iria exibir uma mensagem dizendo que já existe. Mas não está sendo adicionado pois o loop se repete ignorando os dados que eu coloquei anteriormente

Código completo

```
livraria = {'Drama' :1, 'Suspense' :2}

generoA = {'Drama' : 1}

generoB = {'Suspense' : 2}

while op != 0:

    print("""Escolha a opção desejada:

     \n1 - Verificar Gênero A:\n2 - Verificar Gênero B:\n0 - Sair do sistema:""")
    op = int(input())#Escolha da opcao

    if op == 1:

        generoA = input('Insira o tipo de gênero A: ')

        if generoA in livraria:

            print('Já existe')

        else:

            generoA = []

            titulo = input('Insira o título do livro: ')

            genero = input('Insira o gênero do livro: ')

            subgenero = input('Insira o subgenero do livro: ')

            editora = input('Insira a editora do livro: ')

            n_copias = input('Insira a quantidade de copias: ')

            preco = input('Insira o preco do livro: ')

            generoA.append(titulo)

            generoA.append(genero)

            generoA.append(subgenero)

            generoA.append(editora)

            generoA.append(n_copias)

            generoA.append(preco)

            generoA.append(generoA)

    elif op == 2:

        generoB = input('Insira o tipo do gênero B: ')

        if generoB in livraria:

            print('Já existe')

        else:

            generoB = []

            titulo = input('Insira o título do livro: ')

            genero = input('Insira o gênero do livro: ')

            subgenero = input('Insira o subgenero do livro: ')

            editora = input('Insira a editora do livro: ')

            n_copias = input('Insira a quantidade de copias: ')

            preco = input('Insira o preco do livro: ')

            generoB.append(titulo)

            generoB.append(genero)

            generoB.append(subgenero)

            generoB.append(editora)

            generoB.append(n_copias)

            generoB.append(preco)

            generoB.append(generoB)
```

Comment: Olá, seu código foi formatado para uma melhor aparência. Caso queira, é possível editar a postagem. Para isso basta clicar no botão [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/529641/edit).

Comment: Você está sobrescrevendo o valor das variáveis generoA e generoB dentro do `else`

Comment: Desculpa, foi minha primeira pergunta, ainda estou aprendendo a usar essa plataforma, deu para perceber que sou bem iniciante :x, como poderia reverter isso?

Comment: no while esta "op" mas o "op" esta dentro do while..pq.

Answer (score 0):

antes de fazer `generoA = []` você tem que colocar generoA em livraria assim `livraria[generoA] = ...` aí eu não sei que número você quer colocar no lugar desses pontinhos. Se for 3,4,5,6... aí você pode usar `livraria[generoA] = len(livraria)`

claro, isso se op for igual a 1. Se for igual a 2 vc faz `livraria[generoB] = len(livraria)`.